# Yeast for pizza doughs

Tags: pizza, yeast

We are interested in a good quality year-round yeast so we don't have to switch brands or adjust too much according to season.

Comment: Are you having difficulties finding a reliable supplier throughout the year, or having difficulty keeping your store of yeast?

Answer (score 6):

Any good yeast that you bake bread with will do the job.  I have very good success with so-called quick rise or instant yeast, but any of the types will do.   Fresh is more difficult to keep on hand, as it doesn't last as long.

What you will need to adjust seasonally is how much yeast you use and/or how long you let the pizza proof before baking it.   The temperature at which you proof--which is often room temperature in the kitchen--will effect how long it takes the dough to rise.

Comment: I agree, I use SAF instant yeast, which I can freeze.

Comment: Agreed. Don't be put off by the 'quick rise' label - fast action dried yeast is stable, easy to store and easier to use as you don't have to hydrate it first before mixing. You simply use less of it to control the rise.

Answer (score 3):

You can hardly go wrong with an instant yeast, especially SAF. Instant isn't quite as cold-shock tolerant as cake yeast, but it keeps better. On the other hand, active dry yeast still has a couple of advantages, the main ones being the number of legacy recipes out there calibrated for active dry and the fact that it was originally formulated for military kitchens with dubious or no environmental control.